# Overlapping views in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard

I am trying to design two UIViews in storyboard which overlap and are part of same UIviewController. Only one of them is visible at a time so I set alpha to be 0 or 1 in the code depending upon which one I need to show. The problem is I need to layout these views in Storyboard, and the moment I put the second view, the first view in Storyboard does not responds to mouse clicks, even if I set alpha of second view to 0 in the Storyboard. Is there a way to design both the views and modify them anytime at will easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can explore you view controller's view hierarchy (and select any view you want) with the sidebar

[image]

If you don't see the sidebar, tap on the button to expand it
[image]

Comment: How do I move the view around using mouse?

Comment: You can move the view you intend to style forward in the hierarchy, move it around with the mouse and at the end you can bring it back. Otherwise you can set x, y, width and height using the size inspector on the right sidebar (⌥⌘5).